# Translation for custom page with ActiveAdmin

Tags: internationalization, activeadmin

I would like to translate the text just under the menu for a custom page in ActiveAdmin. Normally, this part is connected with the model... but not with a custom page.

I'd like to know, thanks.

My custom page :

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Headers Option" do
  menu priority: 3, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.headers_option") }

  content do
    render partial: 'headers_option'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found. It's simple in fact.

Just need to add

> title: proc{ I18n.t("word.from.langage_yml") } between content and do.

My new code :

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Headers Option" do
  menu priority: 3, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.headers_option") }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.headers_option") }do
    render partial: 'headers_option'
  end
end
```